# DHL Intraship Rate

Tags: api, soap, dhl

Currently i am working in DHL Intraship shipping  integration using

https://www.dhl-geschaeftskundenportal.de

I need shipping rate calculator, in the soap i am not able to find get quote method

```
Methods (15):
        bookPickup(ns1:Version Version, ns0:PickupBookingInformationType BookingInformation, ns0:PickupAddressType PickupAddress, ns0:PickupOrdererType ContactOrderer)
        cancelPickup(ns1:Version Version, xs:string BookingConfirmationNumber)
        createShipmentDD(ns1:Version Version, ns0:ShipmentOrderDDType[] ShipmentOrder)
        createShipmentTD(ns1:Version Version, ns0:ShipmentOrderTDType[] ShipmentOrder)
        deleteShipmentDD(ns1:Version Version, ns1:ShipmentNumberType[] ShipmentNumber)
        deleteShipmentTD(ns1:Version Version, ns1:ShipmentNumberType[] ShipmentNumber)
        doManifestDD(ns1:Version Version, ns1:ShipmentNumberType[] ShipmentNumber)
        doManifestTD(ns1:Version Version, ns1:ShipmentNumberType[] ShipmentNumber)
        getExportDocDD(ns1:Version Version, ns1:ShipmentNumberType[] ShipmentNumber, ns0:DocType DocType)
        getExportDocTD(ns1:Version Version, ns1:ShipmentNumberType[] ShipmentNumber, ns0:DocType DocType)
        getLabelDD(ns1:Version Version, ns1:ShipmentNumberType[] ShipmentNumber)
        getLabelTD(ns1:Version Version, ns1:ShipmentNumberType[] ShipmentNumber)
        getManifestDD(ns1:Version Version, xs:string manifestDate, ns0:manifestDateRange manifestDateRange)
        getVersion(xs:string majorRelease, xs:string minorRelease, xs:string build)
        updateShipmentDD(ns1:Version Version, ns1:ShipmentNumberType ShipmentNumber, ns0:ShipmentOrderDDType ShipmentOrder)
```

**Rate feature is available or not in dhl intraship api.**

If yes then please share the doc / code (in any language)

if not then is it **fixed** per contract / service

Comment: There is no get quote service available for DHL Intraship.